# How to parse a Tuple (String,Int) in Haskell using parsec

Tags: file, haskell, io, parsec

I think i already managed to parse strings to strings and strings to Ints but I also need to parse a (String,Int) type as userRatings is in order to read from a textFile correctly and I am using Parsec

This is the Parsing along with the import

```
import Text.Parsec
( Parsec, ParseError, parse        -- Types and parser
, between, noneOf, sepBy, many1    -- Combinators
, char, spaces, digit, newline     -- Simple parsers
)

-- Parse a string to a string
stringLit :: Parsec String u String
stringLit = between (char '"') (char '"') $ many1 $ noneOf "\"\n"

-- Parse a string to a list of strings
listOfStrings :: Parsec String u [String]
listOfStrings = stringLit `sepBy` (char ',' >> spaces)

-- Parse a string to an int
intLit :: Parsec String u Int
intLit = fmap read $ many1 digit
-- Or `read <$> many1 digit` with Control.Applicative

film :: Parsec String u Film
film = do
-- alternatively `title <- stringLit <* newline` with Control.Applicative
title <- stringLit
newline
director <- stringLit
newline
year <- intLit
newline
userRatings <- listOfStrings
newline
return (title, director, year, userRatings)
```

Comment: Make your code self-contained (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); in particular, add your imports.

Comment: you need to import this in order to see the problem

import Text.Parsec
    ( Parsec, ParseError, parse        -- Types and parser
    , between, noneOf, sepBy, many1    -- Combinators
    , char, spaces, digit, newline     -- Simple parsers
    )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by composing from existing parsers using either the `Applicative` or the `Monad` interface. `Parser` has instances of both.

Using `Applicative`:

```
stringIntTuple :: Parser (String, Int)
stringIntTuple = (,) <$> yourStringParser <*> yourIntParser
```

Which is the same as the following:

```
stringIntTuple :: Parser (String, Int)
stringIntTuple = liftA2 (,) yourStringParser yourIntParser
```

Using `Monad`:

```
stringIntTuple :: Parser (String, Int)
stringIntTuple =
  do
    theString <- yourStringParser
    theInt <- yourIntParser
    return (theString, theInt)
```

Comment: i am still getting this error
Expecting two more arguments to ‘Parsec (String, Int)’
    Expected a type, but ‘Parsec (String, Int)’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
    In the type signature for ‘stringIntTuple’:
      stringIntTuple :: Parsec (String, Int)

Comment: That's because you're using `Parsec` instead of `Parser`.

Comment: when i change everything to Parser it says not in scope

Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Parser’
    Perhaps you meant ‘Parsec’ (imported from Text.Parsec)